# How to increment the header in list

Tags: coq

```
Fixpoint nonzeros (l:natlist) : natlist :=
      match l with
      | nil => nil
      | 0 :: t => 1::nonzeros t
      | h :: t => h :: nonzeros t
     end.
```

I have list of natural numbers with multiple number of zeros. I 
want to replace first zero with one, second zero with two and third 
zero with three and so on, while the rest of the list should remain unchanged.
This function takes a list of natural numbers then replaces zeros 
with ones, but it does not increment it. Is it possible to increment in 
the header before the recursive call?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with this kind of thing, you need to generalise the `1`.
Instead of saying I want to replace the first `0` with `1` and then `2` etc.,
you say, I want to replace the first `0` with `k`, the second with `k+1` and so on.

```
Fixpoint nonzeroes_k (k : nat) (l : list nat) : list nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => nil
  | 0 :: l => k :: nonzeroes_k (S k) l
  | h :: l => h :: nonzeroes_k k l
  end.
```

Then the function you want is the one starting at `1`:

```
Definition nonzeroes := nonzeroes_k 1.
```

You will often do this kind of thing when dealing with offsets in recursive functions.

Comment: Why did you use experimental "Function" command? It requires `FunInd` module. Fixpoint is enough.

Comment: Thank you ,Code works after changing the order of arguments

Comment: Thanks @user4035, that was a typo!